# Page reloading after form submission despite novalidate and false return

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, reload

I started working on the skeleton of a task list maker in JS, and I didn't get too far before noticing that upon submission of a task via a form, the entire page is reloaded, so I'm not able to set text without it disappearing immediately.

I have used `novalidate` in the HTML's form and I'm returning `false` in my function that get's called upon form submission, so I'm not sure what the problem is.  My code is attached in this CodePen: http://cdpn.io/JArfm

Some relevant code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm" novalidate="">
        <fieldset><legend>To-dolist</legend>
            <p>Add things to-do on your list</p>
            <div class="addTasks"><label for="addTask">Event name:</label><input type="text" name="addTask" id="addTask" value="addTask"></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Add task!" id="submit"></div>
            <div id="output"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

JS:

```
(function(){

    function addTask(e){
    'use strict';

    if (typeof e == 'undefined') e = window.event;

    var task = U.$('addTask').value;

    U.setText('output', task);
    return false;
    }


    window.onload = function(){
        "use strict";

        U.addEvent(U.$('theForm'), "submit", addTask);
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently returning false in an event handler function only stops form submission correctly when using the traditional event registration model (`element.onsubmit = doThis;`).  Since I was using the `addEventListener` and `attachEvent` functions, the correct way to deal with this problem (without modifying markup) is to add this to the end of my event handler function:

```
if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    e.returnValue = false;
}
return false;
```

Calling the `preventDefault` method or setting the `returnValue` to `false` (for < IE9) is effective in preventing form submission.

Answer (score 0):

prevent the default action of the input button. You can do this by JQuery's preventDefault() function .Or just `<form onsubmit="return false;"> ... </form>`

Comment: I can see that this works, but I'm looking for a way to do this in the javascript I've written, rather than muddling anything up in the HTML.  Do you have any ideas?  Why is returning false in the addTask function not working on its own?